# is it possible to use view instead of UI Thread?

Tags: android

I m new in android.
i have a little bit confusion in SurfaceView and View......

According to my knowledge..
Views are all drawn on the same GUI thread which is also used for all user interaction.

I want to knw is it possible to create separate thread for the handling

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you define in handling.
If in handling you mean doing calcualtions, downloads etc. then yes.

If by handling you mean splitting control and view up, then no.

Answer (score 0):

If your handling means that handling GUI things in other than GUI thread then Its not possible as Views are coupled with GUI thread or Android Component Activity. But non GUI threads alive even when your activity is finished , and It may leak the references to views. So it has been avided in al most all Programming models. Suppose if you are downloading the some values in Non GUI thread and then update your GUI views and in bwteen your screen orientation takes place and Your activity and its views are  recreated but Non GUI thread is till now keeping the reference to old views . This can create old views to not to be collected by Garbage Collector and leak memory .